# Can't get Image resource with tag

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I want to display an image which is saved within a block schema.

To get the image the following tag should be created `{{ mega_menu_block.settings.menu_image_1 }}` and if I just insert this tag, everything works. The problem is that the number at the end should change to image_2 .. image 3 and so on. I have therefore created a capture tag like so:

```
{%- capture mega_menu_image_id -%}
  mega_menu_block.settings.menu_image_{{ forloop.index }}
{%- endcapture -%}
```

But when I try to reference this like so: `<img src="{{ mega_menu_image_id }}">` in my HTML, this won't work and it returns the following: `<img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1264/0071/t/37/assets/mega_menu_block.settings.menu_image_1?3566">`

This is my schema block code:

```
        "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "mega_menu",
      "name": "Mega menu",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "menu_item",
          "label": "Menu item",
          "info": "Enter menu item to apply a mega menu dropdown. [Learn more](https://support.maestrooo.com/article/180-navigation-enabling-and-configuring-mega-navigation)."
        },
        {
          "type": "header",
          "content": "images for menu title ex. \"iPhone opladere\"",
          "info": "Add images for every header tag. Don't add more than there are tags."
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "menu_image_1",
          "label": "Image",
          "info": "600 x 400px .jpg recommended"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "menu_image_2",
          "label": "Image",
          "info": "600 x 400px .jpg recommended"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "menu_image_3",
          "label": "Image",
          "info": "600 x 400px .jpg recommended"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "menu_image_4",
          "label": "Image",
          "info": "600 x 400px .jpg recommended"
        },
```

What should I do to fix this reference?

Thank you!

Comment: can you please share the `schema` code for the same blocks?

Comment: @Onkar I have updated the question to include schema code

Comment: Is this using `blocks` or into simple `schema` tag?

Comment: Not much clear from your current code.

Comment: This is using blocks. @Onkar

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop over the block and create the IMG link using `img_tag`

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
    {% for i in (1..4) %}
        {% capture img %}menu_image_{{i}}{% endcapture %}
        { block.settings[img] | img_url: 'master' | img_tag }
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```